Can i "outsource" the NLog-portion of appsettings.json?
I have a bunch of different appsettings.json for a number of customers. However, the nLog-portion of these appsettings never changes, so I'd love to have one single json-File for the nLog-config.
So I have something like the following in my appsettings.json:
"NLog": {
    "configFile": "nlog.json"
}

Does anybody know a more or less easy solution for that?

You could try extracting section into separate file and add it with ConfigurationBuilder, like in below example.
I have two settings files:

appsettings.dev.json - all app settings
appsettings.nlog.dev.json - with single NLog section

Both files need to be copied to output directory.
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.dev.json", false)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.nlog.dev.json", false)
    .Build();

using var servicesProvider = new ServiceCollection()
          .AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
          {
              // configure Logging with NLog
              loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
              var nlogConfig = new NLogLoggingConfiguration(config.GetSection("NLog"));
              loggingBuilder.AddNLog(nlogConfig);
          }).BuildServiceProvider();

